# Trouble getting Mathematica to assume some parameters are real and simplify the expression

Tags: simplifying-expressions, complex, assumptions

Say I enter the following code:

```
FullSimplify[Im[r*Exp[I*theta]^2 + (s + I*t)*Exp[I*theta]], 
  Element[theta | r | s | t, Reals]]
```

I expect to get:

```
2*r*Cos[theta]*Sin[theta] + s*Sin[theta] + t*Cos[theta]
```

But what Mathematica gives me is:

```
Im[Exp(I*theta)*(Exp(I*theta)*r + s + I*t)]
```

What's going on, why isn't Mathematica successfully using the assumptions to compute the imaginary part? When I take out any one of the three terms in the original expression, Mathematica successfully produces the simplified output.

Comment: The `See Also` section of the documentation for `FullSimplify` (as well as that for `Simplify`) includes a link to `ComplexExpand`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `ComplexExpand`

```
Simplify[ComplexExpand[Im[r*Exp[I*theta]^2 + (s + I*t)*Exp[I*theta]]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

> I expect to get:
>
> 2*r*Cos[theta]*Sin[theta] + s*Sin[theta] + t*Cos[theta]

It now agrees with what you expected

```
 FullSimplify[sol-(2*r*Cos[theta]*Sin[theta]+s*Sin[theta]+t*Cos[theta])]
 (* 0 *)
```

On 11.1.

I think `ComplexExpand` does a little more than just assumptions on variables being real. It seems to do more special manipulations internally. That is why

```
Assuming[Element[{theta, r,s,t},Reals],
   FullSimplify[Im[r*Exp[I*theta]^2+(s+I*t)*Exp[I*theta]]]]
```

did not give same result as `ComplexExpand`. So when in doubt, use `ComplexExpand`.